# R: Internet routines cannot be loaded after update to R4.0

Tags: r, installation, upgrade, startup

I have an issue that is stumping me and am looking for some help. I just upgraded to R 4.0 and am trying to reinstall packages. This produces the following warning messages:

```
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (internet routines cannot be loaded); using local file 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.0/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.uni-muenster.de/src/contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.uni-muenster.de/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  unable to load shared object 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.0/modules/x64/internet.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  Access is denied.
2: package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 4.0.)
```

Note, the `LoadLibrary failure` is not always present. Additionally, when I look for help on a function (e.g. `?download.file`), I get the following error message:

`starting httpd help server ...Error in startDynamicHelp(TRUE) : internet routines cannot be loaded`

So, it seems like there is a general issue with R connecting to the internet, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. This happens in both RStudio (which is fully updated) and in the base RGui; additionally, I do have access and permissions to read/write in the `C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.0/modules/x64/` folder. Any help here would be much appreciated!

Edit:

Posting my `sessionInfo()` in case that is helpful:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.0 tools_4.0.0
```

Edit 2: I have done some more digging and the 32-bit version of R works just fine, while the 64-bit does not.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue when updated to R 4.0.2 64-bit and ran in RStudio 1.4.xxx which reported internet routine not loaded.  my work cylance protect antivirus quarantined internet.dll file under modules\x64\internet.dll.  I reported to my IT today.  they said that this dll file is asking which antivirus installed in my machine.  so, my IT was concerned.  my IT will ask cylance.

My IT advised me not to download R 402 from cran where it was infected.

i copied that dll from my another pc where R 363 installed and put there.
but cylance antivirus quarantined again.

so i bring my covid analysis file home and am doing with my home R 402.

I checked downloaded R 402 and internet.dll with my windows defender = all clean

the most probable cause = my IT security perceived threat from internet.dll

wondering what others are thinking about it.

I also discussed with my IT director for having r package mirror server so i can download without going to the internet.

cheers.

Comment: my IT gave me R 3.6.1 to complete my covid analyses before the grand round while waiting from cylance that is doing investigation on R 4.0.2 downloaded from cran.  i will update the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Install RStudio and R Version With help of IT Team.**

**Download** New Version of **R** from **CRAN**

**Copy** an `internet.dll` file `(which Size should be Up to 5MB)` from Existing Version Installed by IT Team on Your System

`C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\modules\x64` and

**Paste** it to `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\R\R-4.1.2\modules\x64` folder of New version

Then `Restart RStudio` you will not get any **error**

also you can `install any packages`

Do not need to make changes into any File like `Rprofile and Renv`

Or any other `Options()` Functions

`Note: The File Path may be different in your System`